# Why Apollo mutate never complete?

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, apollo

I stuck with apollo mutation since 2 days.

When i call a mutation on angular apollo generated code and subscribe,  the subscription never complete. I want to get result from the server but nothing is returned.

I dont know why it never complete. When i call directly the graphql server with post request using Postman i get the expected result.

```
 constructor(
    private createAccount: CreateAccountGQL,) {
  }

ngOnInit() {
 this.createAccount.mutate({
      data: {
        uid: 'sdfsdfsdfs',
        username: 'yxydfsdsdsdfsfsfsd',
      },
    }).subscribe(result => {
       // THIS CODE NEVER EXECUTE
       console.log(result)
  });
}
```

Here is the generated code

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class CreateAccountGQL extends Apollo.Mutation<
  CreateAccountMutation,
  CreateAccountVariables
> {
  document: any = gql`
    mutation createAccount($data: AccountCreateInput!) {
      createAccount(data: $data) {
        id
        username
        uid
      }
    }
  `;
}
```

I would like to get some result in my subscribe complete callback.
Please any help
Thank

Comment: Any errors in the console? or do you see any response in the network tab of dev tools? If you share that it will be helpful to check.

Comment: Can you check your network tab in the browser console and see if the request is being executed successfully?

Comment: Hi. There is no error in the network tab and the request is executed successfully with expected response.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. The problem was the GraphQlModule was not imported in my module.

This code work.

```
this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation: gql`mutation createAccount($data: AccountCreateInput!) {
        createAccount(data: $data) {
          id
          username
          uid
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      "data":{
        "uid": "DKpWcH6q2wRCTeUTigrQasdadsVcFfqaS2",
        "username": "ydfsdfsfd@mail.com"
      }
    },
    }).subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```

This code does not work. May be i need to import another module.

```
this.createAccount.mutate({
      data: {
        uid: 'DKpWcH6q2wRCTeUTigrQasdadsVcFfqaS2',
        username: 'ydfsdfsfd@mail.com',
      },
    }).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

Thank